# Get latest build and latest released code from VSO

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8, azure-devops

I need to get the TDS Sitecore folder for the latest successful build and the last successfully released code from VSO. I need the two TDS Sitecore folders so that I can compare the serialized items of the current Sitecore items in my instance and the new build that is supposed to get deployed . I am using the VSO API calls and Powershell to get the data for my project but have not succeeded yet. Please advice.

VSO API Calls: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/overview

Comment: What did you tried so far? Do you have already some (non) working code?

Comment: I tried using VSO API to download the last successful build. But I am not sure whether this is a valid approach. I need to build an update package by comparing the TDS/Sitecore folder items between the last successful release and the latest successful valid build.

Comment: what are you using for source control? If you have Git you can add tags to your build to enable comparing of the two serialised folders. Explained in detail here - http://goblinrockets.com/2013/11/03/continuous-integration-deployment-with-sitecore/

Comment: I am using TFS and VSO

Comment: Your answer is confusing. VSTS (was VSO) and TFS both support two source control systems. Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and Git. Which are you using?

Comment: Sorry! We are using TFVC

Comment: What do you want to download? The build artifact or the source code of the build?